# EPiServer 9 Navigation-/Assetspane not showing

Tags: websocket, dojo, episerver

I've recently updated our stageserver for a project to the latest EPiServer version. It all worked fine on my local pc, but I encountered some problems with the WebSocket on the Windows Server 2012.

After some searching I managed to get it to work without the ugly "real-time message", by adding:

```
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"
```

to my webconfig.

Although, now when I login into EPiServer CMS, both my assets and my navigation pane are all gray. Any ideas how to solve this? Can't find anything online.

[image: Navigation pane]

*Edit
When removing targetFramework="4.5" from my web.config, it's working, although I recieve the "real-time connection" message again. 
[image: Real-time error]

**Edit 2

Just noticed that all my tabs have been move under the assets pane, it looks weird and I cannot move it nor' add it to the navigation pane side.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this, I had forget to reset my views inside my profile within episerver. It's working now!

Thanks for your time Ted!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, ensure you have **web sockets** enabled on your web server, it is a requirement as of later versions for the Episerver UI.

**Edit:** Also, you should target **.NET 4.6.1** and may also want to turn on client resources debugging for more exhaustive errors in the console: http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Ben-McKernan/Dates/2014/8/Uncompressed-JavaScript-for-EPiServer-76/

Comment: Yes, it's installed through the Server Manager.

Comment: That's odd. :/ Any console errors? Also, see answer edit.